# One class confusion matrix notation for model evaluation

Tags: model-evaluations, performance, confusion-matrix, one-class-classification

A one class classification set-up for a set of rules acting as a model, where

- each input is a whole dataset
- model makes some decision within the dataset for each entry
- output is decisions made for each entry for that particular input
- reference standard judges whether the output is correct, calling it a "non-positive" if even one decision made for any entry is incorrect

Does this set-up make sense? Since I only have a say on positives, does using precision based on this reference standard(ground truth) make sense? I feel like there are gaps in this logic but can't pin-point where.